# design container with fixed value

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, react-animated

I am trying to create a Card in React which look like the first one on the left:

[image]

So I have created a class as below (plz do not take care of the immage, I just play with the text position for now)

```
import React from 'react';
import BlueButton from '../materialdesign/BlueButton'
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

class ClassCard extends React.Component {  

    render() {
        const tileStyle = {
            postion: "absolute",
            topMargin: "100px !important",
            textAlign: "center",
            width: "300px",
            height: "460px",
            margin: "20px",
            backgroundColor: "#999999",
            boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
            borderRadius: 21, 
        }

        const titleStyle = {
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "200px",
            fontFamily: "Fredoka One",
            fontSize: 20 ,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            color: "#ffffffff",
        }

        const descStyle = {
            display: "inline-block",
            width: "200px",
            fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
            fontSize: 14 ,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "#ffffffff",
        }

        return(
                <Container style={tileStyle}>
                    <div>
                        <p style={titleStyle}>{this.props.title}</p>
                        <p style={descStyle}>{this.props.desc}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style={{position: "relative", bottom: "-100px", top:"auto !important"}}>
                        <BlueButton textSize="14" link_href="#" text={TextContents.BookBtn} />
                    </div>
                </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default ClassCard;
```

I am trying to make sure that the title is always fixed at the same margin from the top, same for the descriptio and also the book button always at the same place from the bottom. The goal is to make sure that if all the cards are aligned, it has all title, desc and button aligned.

Also, I can't find a way to create an animation to do a nice effect. What I am trying to achieve is when the card is selected or the mouse point is hover, you can see title, desc and button. When not focus or selected or hover, every look like slide down to only display the title. like seen on the second picture on the image above.

The effect should look like slide up and down

Any idea how to fix the position of the text and do this animation

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use `position:absoulut` to do the positioning

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 40%;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 500px;
            background: lightblue;
        }

        .title {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10%;
        }
        .des {
            position: absolute;
            top: 30%;
        }
        .btn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">This is a title</p>
        <p class="des">This is a discription</p>
        <button class="btn">buttom</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">This is a title</p>
        <button class="btn">buttom</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Guichi/pen/OJMLrKZ)